# Magicians Problem

Tags: probability, statistics

Consider a competition for magicians. The point of the competition is to prove to the general audience that there is no such thing as magical abilities at all, so the organizers hope that nobody wins simply due to luck.

The procedure of the competition is as follows. A fair coin is tossed 11 times and the magician tries to guess the results of these tosses. The organizers of the competition test null hypothesis that claims that probability to guess is 1/2 against an alternative that this probability is larger than 1/2. If null hypothesis is rejected on 5% significance level, then the organizers will claim that the magician has magical abilities and pay him his winning money.

Assume that 50 magicians participate in the competition and try to prove that they have magical abilities. All magicians are tested independently. What is the probability that at least one magician wins (and therefore the organizers have to conclude that people with magical abilities exist).

Enter answer with 2 digits after decimal point.

- Ans: W : no. of magicians out of 50 who wins
- W ~ Binom(n=50, p = 0.5)
- P(W >= 1) = 1 - P(W=0)
- 0.92 but this not correct answer`

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Where have you used the information about rejecting the null hypothesis at the $5\%$ significance level?  Where does $.02$ come from?

Comment: It seems to me that the first step is to calculate which score a magician must get to be in the 5 % category and win. With the probability P that a magician wins, you can then calculate other things.

Comment: **Outline:** To win a magician must _guess_ 9 or more tosses correctly with probability $p=0.0327.$ (There is no test exactly at 5% because binomial is discrete,) // For probability of no win among 50 magicians it's $(1-.0327)^{50} =0.1897.$ // These are exact computations using R: Normal or Poisson approximations may give slightly different answers. // How about answering your own question and maybe getting upvotes for that?